# Finding TD Innertext, can this be simplified?

Tags: php, csv, simple-html-dom, innertext

So I have a large table (701-ish rows, 19 columns). I need to extract the innertext in each td, and then I write it to a csv. The problem is, this takes forever. Doing just 100, takes 32 seconds. This is the code I have:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < 100; $j++)
    {
        $f = $html->find("td",$j); // get the td elements from the html
        $rowArray[] = $f->innertext; // store that text inside the array

        if(($j+1) % 19 == 0) // hit the end of the row
        {
            $txt .= implode(",", $rowArray) . "\r\n"; // format with comma's and throw it into $txt
            unset($rowArray); //  clear the array, for the next record              
            $rowArray = array(); // re-set the array
        }
    }
```

The 100 is a temporary value while I test, it really is closer to 13000. The biggest issue is finding the TD values. Is there a faster way for this or is this as good as I can get it?

Basically, looking for the quickest way to extract TD data from an HTML table so I can write it to a CSV.

Comment: I'd try writing to the file as I parse each row. See [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#refsect1-function.fwrite-notes). (**Edited** I wanted the section above that one.)

Comment: Post the HTML table - Although it's not as nice as HTML parsing, you _could_ use a regex to pull all the content you need.

Comment: The table is stored in the .txt file, but basically it's all stripped down. So the only tags are <table><tr><td>. 701ish Rows, 19 cols in each row. Would regex be faster than Simple HTML DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Did a str_replace to get the stuff I didn't want out and was able to get the contents a lot quicker and faster.